# How to escape string for SQL query (without prepared statement)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I know the power of prepared statement, but I can't use it here. I send sql queries to external server via HTTP, not via JDBC.
How to escape string for SQL query? There is way to do this via JDBC? or I should use custom class/function for this?

p.s. Also I have connection to other DB, so I can use JDBC functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very insecure. If you're sending SQL statements over the HTTP, then you could get compromised by man-in-the-middle attacks (among others). Apart from this, any average leveled programmer could attempt to execute malicious SQL against your database, if they see you're sending SQL statements around. They could create users, change passwords, retrieve sensitive data... Are you sure this is the best way to approach things?

Answer (score 1):

I know links dont really make good answers - but this [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) is an excellent read (and way too big to post on here) if you are unable to use Prepared Statements - it gives you lots of examples on how to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: try this 
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql

Answer (score 1):

Despite the others already told, that it is not a good idea. You can just "mimic" the behaviour of PreparedStatement via your HTTP call.

Just send multiple parameters within the call like

```
/sqlInterperter.do?sql=somesql_with_params&param1=...&param2=...
```

Then atleast you can use prepared statements again on the receiving side.

(Nevertheless anyone could send you any statements! So best is: Don't do it)

Answer (score 0):

[Read this](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jdbc.html#esc) which has this:

```
static public String escapeLine(String s) {
  String retvalue = s;
  if (s.indexOf ("'") != -1 ) {
    StringBuffer hold = new StringBuffer();
    char c;
    for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
      if ((c=s.charAt(i)) == '\'' ) {
      hold.append ("''");
    }else {
      hold.append(c);
    }
  }
  retvalue = hold.toString();
  }
  return retvalue;
}
```

Comment: What happens if th user supplies a string with the escape character `'\'` in it?  Such as `bobby\' AND \'1\' = \'1`?

Comment: Link is broken, thanks for remembering to dump the relevant code here though!