# Order by descending ID PDO query

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get results from the database and I would like to show the info starting from the last ID, not the first one, is this possible?

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grafica WHERE ID = :id");
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row) {


}
```

Comment: "`SELECT ...   ORDER BY id DESC, foo DESC`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `ID` is unique, so your question does not currently make sense in context of the query posted: the query will return exactly 1 or 0 rows, depending on if a row with `ID = :id` exists.  If you want to view a list of rows, perhaps in ascending or descending order of ID, do not restrict the results with `ID = :id`, and use the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grafica ORDER BY ASC");
# $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grafica ORDER BY DESC");  # for descending order
$query->execute();
```

Note that there is now no need for the `bindParam` call.

Comment: I have replaced ID = :id for only Id desc. Is this secure? Thanks

Comment: In this limited context, yes.  The SQL query would not be created with any user-sent input and will be exactly as you, the programmer, intended.  This SQL, without string interpolation, has no chance for a user to change its intent.  As an aside: kudos for using prepared statements already.  For a _little_ more on the security aspect, [peruse this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272504/getting-rid-of-sql-injection-without-using-prepared-statement), specifically the edit.